# DevBox with magento2 (2.1.6) doesn't reach the proxy in docker container

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, proxy

I installed the magento2 devbox behind a proxy. My problem is that on the web container the env are not set.

So just to clarify I have in .env a filed `http_proxy=ip` (that works when I install the whole devbox), then I added extra and `- http_proxy=ip` in the `docker-compose.yml` under the `environment:`.

Now when I ssh into the web container and check it with `env` I see no `http_proxy` variable. What should I do to set this variable when the container starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had two problems:

1. Everytime when I started a ssh the `http_proxy` variable was not initiated.

   For that I had to change the `/etc/profile` and add there the `export http_proxy = my ip`
2. The magento component was not working.

   I had added a second repository to the `composer.json` to load the libraries from the packagist repository in order to unit test my extension. As result of adding this repo the component manager was loading until the whole webshop crashed. To resolve this I removed this repository and leave just the magento repo.